# newform and editform not displaying all appended column

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I've added a append column to my list. In the default (OOTB) dispform.aspx and editform.aspx I can see the appended data.

I then create a new dispform.aspx (in SPD) and I can only see the last appended entry. All previous entries are missing). The same applies to editform.aspx.

Does anyone know how to correct this? This is the code inserted into the page:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Action" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raj,

Replace that with below:

```
<SharePoint:AppendOnlyHistory FieldName="Action" runat="server" ControlMode="Display" ItemId="{@ID}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Whats the difference, is this outputting differently somehow using XSLT ?
Can I add scroll bars, output text is long?

Comment: The difference is of the Control... the XSLT renders only a link to display form while this Control AppendOnlyHistory renders complete versions... Now about adding a scroll bar, I guess you can simply add a div and see how can you add scroll bars to div...

Comment: What I meant was do these controls deal with xml rendering differently. Is there more than one way to output html ?

Comment: Don't know the other way, this always works well :)